# In Rails 5, how do I prevent find_by from returning a result if none exists?

Tags: model, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I"m using Rails 5.  I'm confused about looking up a record by its ID.  I have a model, User, but when I look up with a nil id, I get back a result ...

```
2.4.0 :002 > User.find_by(nil)
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<User id: 2, provider: "google_oauth2", uid: "10152354902902839283465", email: "user@hotmail.com", first_name: "Dave", last_name: "LastName", oauth_token: nil, oauth_expires: nil, created_at: "2017-08-28 19:49:18", updated_at: "2017-09-04 20:03:36", last_login: nil, currency_id: nil, email_confirmed: false, confirm_email_key: nil, confirm_key_expires: nil>
```

How do I look up an active record by its ID but have it return nil if no ID matches the given parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters you are passing to `find_by` define the condition to apply to the query -- `find_by(*args)` is just `where(*args).take`.

The code you show, `User.find_by(nil)`, is the same as passing in no condition, so is equivalent to `User.where(nil).take`, or `User.take`, resulting in a query equivalent to `select * from users limit 1`.

If you want to search by id and not have an error thrown when you pass nil or a value that doesn't exist, use:

```
User.find_by(id: id)
```

If you want an error to be thrown if the id doesn't exist then use:

```
User.find(id)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I still contend that User.find_by(id) where id is nil yet returns results is way confusing.

Comment: Yes it is, but it's a very unorthodox way of using the method. The method expects to be supplied with a condition, usually in the form of a hash (although a SQL fragment could be used).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to utilize BEGIN and RESCUE.

```
begin
  User.find(id)
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  p "Display error here"
end
```

One-liner:

```
User.where(id: 'id').present? ? User.find('id') : nil
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a one-line solution.  Looking up a record by its id can't be that hard.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-line solution:

```
User.where(id: id).first
```

This assumes your `id` column is not nullable (which is usually the case).  If not you can do:

```
User.where(id: id).where.not(id: nil).first
```

Comment: No my ID is not nullable.  Why is the statement I listed in my question failing?

Comment: `User.where(id: id).first` is semantically not quite the same as using `find_by`, as the `first` applies an `order by id` to the query which is not present with `find_by`. For finding a single `id` where ids are unique the result is equivalent, of course, but maybe not for other types of column.